# Standard $n$-simplex is not a Kan complex

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

In Lurie's Kerodon it is mentioned as a remark that none of the standard $n$-simplices, i.e. the representable simplicial sets, are Kan complexes. I am curious to see a proof of this 'straight from the definition'. That is, I would like to see why we can't extend every morphism  $\Lambda^k_i\to \Delta^n$ to a morphism $\Delta^k\to \Delta^n$.

I have tried a few things, but not really anything mentionable. Any help is welcome!

edit: as an administrator pointed out, the case $n=1$ is indeed already given as an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3844959/simplicial-sets-which-are-not-kan-complexes). However, I am still interested in a generalization to arbitrary $n$.

Comment: The same explanation can be given. There is a map $\Lambda^2_0\to \Delta^n$given by $0\to 1$ and $0\to 0$ which cannot be filled due to the absence of any edge $1\to 0$.

Comment: So in fact this even shows that we can't even extend the map $\Lambda^2_0\to \Delta^n$ to a map $\partial \Delta^2\to \Delta^n$ right?

Comment: Yep, that's right.